# Controlling led strip with SPI bus causes entire strip to light up

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, spi, led

I am using python package to control a led strip.
Using PWM everything worked perfectly fine but it didn't allow me to run the script without sudo which is why I switched over to using SPI.

Now I get this weird behaviour where suddenly the entire led strip lights up but in kind of a gradient:

The strip is connected to GND, 5V, and GPIO10 / MOSI / Pin 19.

Example usage of the Strip:

```
#strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(led_count, led_pin, led_freq_hz, led_dma, led_invert, led_brightness, led_channel)
strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(110, 10, 800000, 10, False, 255, 0)
# PWM would have GPIO 18 as led_pin
# strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(110, 18, 800000, 10, False, 255, 0)
strip.begin()
strip.setPixelColor(0, Color(255, 255, 255))
strip.show()
```

Comment: To clarify, you were *not* seeing this behavior when controlling the strip with PWM? This is something new that emerged only after switching to SPI? I would suspect this is something more to do with the LEDs themselves and/or their positioning, rather than something controlled by code. But I have no specific experience with this platform. Might be helpful to post the PWM code in the question, just for comparison purposes? (Sorry about the earlier noise where someone told you not to post images of code. That was obviously inapplicable; I've removed comments about it.)

Comment: @ Cody Gray – exactly, I was using PWM for the whole development process but now when I worked on a simple deployment instruction I noticed that apache can't run the app with sudo which forced me to use SPI which can be configured to work without root permission.

Comment: Im putting the PWM code up there, but its really just another pin 

Yeah, thanks for removing that, I am working on this led project forever now and its really frustrating to simply get this running in a real web server instead of the builtin dev server in flask ...

Comment: PWM and SPI are completely different HW pieces, I'm completely puzzled how you even possible considered SPI as replacement for PWM.

Comment: Because the python module I used to control the strip supports both. When Using PWM, I didn't need to specify that I want to use PWM  – I don't know how the module works under its hood, but I gave up trying to get it to work (it worked sometimes, my solution therefore was not completely bad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution does no longer apply.